# Get current custom user taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, author

I’m using the plugin [User Groups](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-groups/) which lets me group users with categories. The plugin is working essentially the same as using the manual method (custom user taxonomies) described by [Justin Tadlock here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress).

On author.php I want to list the taxonomies the currently viewed user belongs to, and each list item should link to the taxonomy term page.

I use the following code to get current user ID and retrieve custom field values from the profile page:

```
<?php // Get current author

$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

?>
```

And I use the following code to list the custom user taxonomies:

```
<?php // List custom user taxonomies

wp_list_categories('taxonomy=user-group');

?>
```

"taxonomy=user-group" is fetching all of the terms created within the plugin.

[Here’s a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502811/display-current-post-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress) to get current post taxonomies, but I’m looking to change it to custom user taxonomies.

Is there a way for me to change wp_list_categories() to only display the taxonomies I want? Should I be looking for another approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try this suggestion:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();  // Get current user Id
$user_groups = wp_get_object_terms($user_id, 'user-group', array('fields' => 'all_with_object_id'));  // Get user group detail
foreach($user_groups as $user_gro)
{
    echo $user_gro->name; // Get current user group name
    echo $user_gro->taxonomy; // get current user taxonomy 
}
```

Comment: Hi @kruti : "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Rather than just post code, please try to provide a description/explanation of your code and include why you think it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. I ditched the plugin and got another one called [User Taxonomies.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-taxonomies/) It does all the boring part of creating custom taxonomies (saving fields etc.) You will do just as well by writing it all yourself, but i wanted to keep my code clean.

After installing the plugin I registered my custom taxonomies manually like described on the plugin page, but added `hierarchy => true` to make the taxonomy act like categories instead of like tags. To allow multi selection on the profile-page i added this code to the plugin document user-taxonomies.php:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $key?>[]" id="<?php echo "{$key}-{$term->slug}"?>" value="<?php echo $term->slug?>" <?php checked(true, is_object_in_term($user->ID, $key, $term))?> />
```

Then I had to change the saving of fields with this function (added to the same file:

```
/**
 * Save the custom user taxonomies when saving a users profile
 *
 * @param Integer $user_id  - The ID of the user to update
 */
public function save_profile($user_id) {
    foreach(self::$taxonomies as $key => $taxonomy) {
        // Check the current user can edit this user and assign terms for this taxonomy
        if(!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id) && current_user_can($taxonomy->cap->assign_terms)) return false;
        // Save the data
        $user_terms = ! is_array($_POST[$key]) ? array($_POST[$key]) : $_POST[$key];
        wp_set_object_terms($user_id, $user_terms, $key, false);
        clean_object_term_cache($user_id, $key);
    }
}
```

To show the taxonomy terms which the user belongs to, I used the following snippet:

```
<?php the_terms( $curauth->ID, 'NAME-OF-TAXONOMY');?></p>
```

Hope this helps someone. [Credit goes to Timothy Wood and benjaminniess.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-user-taxonomies-allow-multiple-select-for-each-user-taxonomy?replies=8)

Comment: FWIW you are really answering a whole other question here, that being: "How can I enable multiple-selections in a user taxonomy".